# Problems with mailenable when sending to yahoo mail

Tags: webmail, email

I'm testing sending emails from [mailenable](http://www.mailenable.com/) webmail. I have no problems sending mail to gmail or hotmail, both work fine, but yahoo mail sends my messages to the spam folder and shows the attachment icon for the message even though the message doesn't contain any attachments, it's just plain text. It only includes a reply to a previous message, like this:

```
message text

----- Original Message -----

original message text
```

I copied the message content and sent it from gmail to yahoo and the attachment icon didn't show which makes me believe it's something with mailenable. What could possibly be wrong?

Also, is there a white list for yahoo mail that I can join? And also for other popular webmail? I'm going to use this on a production website (site visitors use the contact us form to send messages to the site - the mail enable server running on the same machine as the web server - then I check the messages using the mailenable webmail and reply them).

This is really important to me, your help would be really appreciated ...

Comment: Belongs on superuser

Comment: No! it's something that I have to configure in mailenable, what does superuser has to do with this?!

Comment: @duffbeer - Disagree.  He's talking about web dev etc

Answer (score 1):

There are definitely some things you should look into when sending email to Hotmail/Yahoo.

First, the MSN Postmaster:

[Sender Solutions](http://postmaster.msn.com/Services.aspx#SenderSolutions)

Then, the Yahoo! end:

[Yahoo Postmaster](http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/mail/postmaster//basics/;_ylt=AkkL4FGjviz2fBiaEnC9zd9vMiV4)

If your mail is not being delivered successfully to the major free email providers, *read the above links very thoroughly*.

Hope that helps.